# Unknown Syntax error:"keyword argument repeated". Just Why?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import random, requests

from datetime import datetime

from sys import getsizeof

#FileHanlder & DataHandler is a some other supporting class

class Requester:

    """A class for making HTTP requests."""

    def __init__(self, agent=None, header=None, proxy=None, ref=None, ref_file=None, proxy_file=None, agent_file=None, set_agent=False, set_header=False, set_ref=False, set_proxy=False, break_pt=None):

        self.agent = 0
        self.ref = 0
        self.proxy = 0
        self.header = 0
        self.break_pt = break_pt

        if agent_file is not None:
            self.agent = FileHandler.read(agent_file)
        elif set_agent:
            self.agent = agent
        else:
            self.agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'

        if ref_file is not None:
            self.ref = FileHandler.read(ref_file).split('\n')
        elif set_ref:
            self.ref = ref

        if proxy_file is not None:
            self.proxy = FileHandler.read(proxy_file).split('\n')
        elif set_proxy:
            self.proxy = proxy

        if set_header:
            self.header = header

    def request(self, url, method='get', params=None, data=None, json=None, headers=None, cookies=None, timeout=5, redirect=True, verify=True, proxy=None, ref=None, agent=None, break_pt=None):

        if break_pt is None:
            break_pt = self.break_pt

        if break_pt is not None:
            time.sleep(random.uniform(break_pt[0], break_pt[1]))

        if agent is None:
            agent = self.agent

        if ref is None:
            ref = self.ref

        if proxy is None:
            proxy = self.proxy

        if headers is None:
            headers = self.header

        if method.lower() == 'get':
            ret = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=redirect, verify=verify, proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': agent, 'Referer': ref})
        elif method.lower() == 'post':
            ret = requests.post(url, params=params, data=data, json=json, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=redirect, verify=verify, proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': agent, 'Referer': ref})
        elif method.lower() == 'put':
            ret = requests.put(url, params=params, data=data, json=json, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=redirect, verify=verify, proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': agent, 'Referer': ref})
        elif method.lower() == 'patch':
            ret = requests.patch(url, params=params, data=data, json=json, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=redirect, verify=verify, proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': agent,'Referer': ref})
        elif method.lower() == 'delete':
            ret = requests.delete(url,params=params,data=data, json=json, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=redirect, verify=verify, proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': agent,'Referer': ref})

        return ret

if '__main__'==__name__:

    t = Requester.request('https://www.google.com/').status_cod
    print( 'ok' if (t==200) else 'failed')
```

This code when ever I run, it shows the syntax error of "keyword argument repeated" at line no:-59

```
ret = requests.delete(...)
```

I don't know how to fix it.

I was trying to make a method that automatically does http/https request to the url that i need and automatic provide with headers and all the other stuff.

Comment: Well, you're trying to pass two values of `headers`...

Comment: '"keyword argument repeated". Just Why?'—because you're repeating a keyword argument. Did you search that error message to see what it means, and then look for repeated keyword arguments in your code?

Comment: Side note: this would have been a lot easier to spot if that very long line had been broken into a few nicely-formatted lines.

Comment: What would you want Python to do with two different `headers` arguments? Use the first one, the last one, try to merge them? Python simply doesn't allow multiple occurrences, forcing you to be explicit about what you actually want.